# How can I pre-populate a field based on a connection.js query result?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, ajax

The query itself seems to work, but getting its result (the Campaign Name) into the desired field doesn't work.

As it is, the code results in the field being populated with: `{done:'true', queryLocator:null, records:{type:'Campaign', Id:'7010J000001FgG2QAK', }, size:'1', }`, while changing the values to `CampaignRec.CampaignName` or `CampaignRec.CampaignId` results in the text "undefined" appearing in the field instead.

See code below:

```
<apex:page standardController="CampaignMember">
<script src="/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<apex:form >
    <apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:messages />
        <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputfield value="{!campaignmember.campaignid}" label="Campaign Name" id="CampaignMemberCampaignId"/>     
                <script>
                    sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}'; 
                    var CampaignRec = sforce.connection.query('SELECT Id,Name FROM Campaign WHERE CreatedDate=TODAY');
                    document.getElementById('{!$Component.CampaignMemberCampaignId}' + '_lkid').value = CampaignRec;
                    document.getElementById('{!$Component.CampaignMemberCampaignId}' + '_lkold').value = CampaignRec;
                    document.getElementById('{!$Component.CampaignMemberCampaignId}' + '_mod').value = 1;
                    document.getElementById('{!$Component.CampaignMemberCampaignId}').value = CampaignRec;     
                </script>
```

Edit: It returns a record now, that fits into the criteria. I've edited the question details accordingly.

Comment: You are getting `0` records. Please check the filter criteria. Query was executed fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in the [Documentation Examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm), you need to use `getArray` on the returned results to obtain the actual data returned by a query.

```
result = sforce.connection.query("Select Name, Id from User");
records = result.getArray("records");

for (var i=0; i< records.length; i++) {
  var record = records[i];
  log(record.Name + " -- " + record.Id);
}
```

---

For your case, you will need to set `LIMIT 1` in your query to ensure you get the correct result (as opposed to several results), and then access this result via calling `getArray` on the `records` property of the returned object.

```
var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, Name FROM Campaign WHERE CreatedDate=TODAY LIMIT 1");
var records = result.getArray("records");

if (records.length === 1) {
    var record = records[0];

    document.getElementById('{!$Component.CampaignMemberCampaignId}' + '_lkid').value = record.Id;
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.CampaignMemberCampaignId}' + '_lkold').value = record.Name;
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.CampaignMemberCampaignId}' + '_mod').value = 1;
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.CampaignMemberCampaignId}').value = record.Name; 
}
```